# Android Fatal Exception due to array

Tags: android, arrays, fatal-error

I am becoming crazy... I got this message on logs when running my APP and even if should be clear the mistake I cannot find any index of array that is in overflow... can someone help me ?

07-04 19:53:07.538: E/AndroidRuntime(11378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 19:53:07.538: E/AndroidRuntime(11378): Process: com.xyz.abcd, PID: 11378
07-04 19:53:07.538: E/AndroidRuntime(11378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smartweb.sungame/com.xyz.abcd.level7x7}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=49; index=-1

Comment: The error clearly says it `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=49; index=-1`. You are trying to access `someArray[-1]`. Can you post a piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem... I filled the array till the length, but unfortunately the length was wrongly calculated so ate the end it became a negative index into the array.